Exit Intent Popup that only triggers while leaving the top of the screen?
More of a hypothetical question that I was curious about. Has anyone ever been able to create an exit intent popup that only triggers if the user moves the mouse off the top of the screen?
I have exit intent popups that are triggered based off the user leaving the "HTML" on the page so it basically doesn't matter where the user moves the mouse off the screen but is it possible to get it to work so it only triggers if the user moves their mouse toward the browsers close and/or refresh button and not to trigger if they go off the bottom of the browser?
Sorry in advance if that is confusing, trying to figure out the best way to word it.
Thanks!
